# Get tapped / swiped item in ListViewrenderer for Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to get the item tapped / swiped in Xamarin Android ListViewRenderer.  Does anyone know? Here is what I have basically - in my event of swipe / tap I need to get the ListViewItem

```
public class MyListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
  {
      listener = new MyGestureListener();
      detector= new GestureDetector(listener);
      listener.OnTapped += HandleTapped;
}

    private void HandleTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // how to get the tapped item here?
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need **CustomList** and **CustomViewCell** in your PCL Project.

**CustomViewCell(XML)**

```
<ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="CellBaseLayout" >
            <Label x:Name="lblName"  Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackLayout>
</ViewCell.View>
```

**CustomViewCell(.CS)**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        public delegate void CellTapedEvent(object source, EventArgs e);

        public event CellTapedEvent CellTaped;
        public CustomViewCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped;
            CellBaseLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Name", typeof(string), typeof(CustomViewCell), "");

        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }

        public int NumberOfTapsRequired { get { return tapGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired; } set { tapGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = value; } }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CellTaped?.Invoke(this, e);

        }

        private TapGestureRecognizer tapGestureRecognizer;
        public TapGestureRecognizer TapGestureRecognizer { get { return tapGestureRecognizer; } }

    }
```

**CustomList**

```
 public class CustomList : ListView
    {

        public delegate void CellItemTapedEvent(object source, EventArgs e);

        public event CellItemTapedEvent CellItemTaped;
        public CustomList() :base()
        {

        }


        protected override void SetupContent(Cell content, int index)
        {
            base.SetupContent(content, index);
            if(content is CustomViewCell)
            {
                CustomViewCell cell = (CustomViewCell)content;
                cell.CellTaped += Cell_CellTaped;
            }

        }



        private void Cell_CellTaped(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            CellItemTaped?.Invoke(source, e);
        }

        protected override void UnhookContent(Cell content)
        {
            if (content is CustomViewCell)
            {
                CustomViewCell cell = (CustomViewCell)content;
                cell.CellTaped -= Cell_CellTaped;
            }
            base.UnhookContent(content);
        }
    }
```

**MainPage(XML)**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <local:CustomList x:Name="ItemList">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:CustomViewCell NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Name="{Binding Name}">
                        </local:CustomViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </local:CustomList>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**MainPage(.cs)**

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ItemRepo ItemRepo = null;
         public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ItemRepo = new ItemRepo();
            ItemList.ItemsSource = ItemRepo.Items; 
        }       
    }
```

**ListViewRendere**

```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomList), typeof(MyListView))]
    namespace ListViewRendererCross.Droid
    {
       public class MyListView : ListViewRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (e.OldElement != null)
                {
                    // unsubscribe
                    if (e.NewElement is CustomList)
                    {
                        CustomList list = (CustomList)e.NewElement;
                        list.CellItemTaped -= List_CellItemTaped;

                    }

                }
                var th = this;
                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    // subscribe
                    if(e.NewElement is CustomList)
                    {
                        CustomList list = (CustomList)e.NewElement;
                        list.CellItemTaped += List_CellItemTaped;

                    }

                }

            }

            private void List_CellItemTaped(object source, EventArgs e)
            {
//Hear you will get your Taped Item
                Item SelectedItem = (Item)((CustomViewCell)source).BindingContext;
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.BaseActivity);
                AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
                alert.SetTitle("Alert");
                alert.SetMessage("Name : " + SelectedItem.Name + "  ,  Rate : " + SelectedItem.Rate);
                alert.Show();
            }


        }



     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Custom Cells](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/) and in View cell Use Layout for TapGestureRecognizer.

Please Check Sample Code.

```
 public class Item
    {
        public int id  { get;set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemRepo
    {
        public ItemRepo()
        {
            CreateItem();
        }

         public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public void CreateItem()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=1, Name = "A-104",Rate = 50 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=2, Name = "B-104", Rate = 55 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=3, Name = "B-806", Rate = 70 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=4, Name = "B-107", Rate = 95 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=5, Name = "A-105", Rate = 80 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=6, Name = "A-106", Rate = 72 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=7, Name = "C-188", Rate = 32 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=8, Name = "C-194", Rate = 58 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=9, Name = "D-897", Rate = 88 });
            Items.Add(new Item() {id=10, Name = "D-968", Rate = 60 });

        }
    }
```

**ListView XML** 
 : check Stack layout TapGestureRecognizer and CommandParameter is use to passing id (key) which use to get selected object.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <ListView x:Name="ItemList">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers >
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2"  Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding id}"  />
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Label x:Name="lblName" Text="{Binding Name}"    />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**Listview Code behind**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ItemRepo ItemRepo = null;
         public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ItemRepo = new ItemRepo();
            ItemList.ItemsSource = ItemRepo.Items;
        }

         private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Item SelectedItem = ItemRepo.Items.FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.id == Convert.ToInt32(((TappedEventArgs)e).Parameter.ToString()));
            if (SelectedItem != null)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert", "Name : " +SelectedItem.Name + "  ,  Rate : " + SelectedItem.Rate, "OK");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I really need to do it in the Renderer as it will also have swipe and other gestures.  Currently I have it working in the ViewRenderer for the part that Recycler reuses gestures and causes other views to be swiped or touched

Comment: I need some time to implement this in ListViewRenderer.